# OutputCache só é valido a nível de controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, cache

Tenho lido o artigo:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

E comecei a utilizar o:

```
   [OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "none")]
```

Quando coloco na controller percebo nitidamente a diferença.

Porém quando estou usando em uma biblioteca que é chamada pela minha *controller*, parece que o cache não acontece.

O código é o seguinte:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, VaryByParam = "none")]
    internal IEnumerable<CPUStats> ProcessarStatsSQL()
    {
        var DateQuery = db.servidorSQL.ToList().Select(o => new CPUStats
        {
            Data = DateTime.Parse(o.Data, new CultureInfo("en-US")),
            CPU = Double.Parse(o.CPU,new CultureInfo("en-US")),
            RAM = Double.Parse(o.RAM, new CultureInfo("en-US")),
            Disco = Double.Parse(o.Disco, new CultureInfo("en-US"))
        });

        return DateQuery;
    }

 [OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public DateTime Data_SQL()
        {
            var DateQuery = ProcessarStatsSQL();

            var Data = DateQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.Data).Take(1).ToList();

            return (DateTime)Data.FirstOrDefault().Data;
        }
 [OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public Double IO_SQL()
        {
            var DateQuery = ProcessarStatsSQL();

            var IO = DateQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.Data).Take(5).ToList();

            return (double)IO.Average(a => a.Disco);
        }
```

**Ou seja o**  `IO_SQL()` e `Data_SQL()` **não deveria utilizar o cache já feito anteriormente?**

Mas no debug vejo que ele processa a consulta no DataBase para cada `IO_SQL()` e `Data_SQL()`

**Posso utilizar em um HtmlHelper?**

```
  [OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public static IHtmlString VerificaRAM(this HtmlHelper helper)
```

Comment: Você já fez o teste usando um `Duration` maior e sem debug? O debug força a expiração da *cache*.

Comment: já...cacheoutput não funciona em uma classe fora da controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o próprio nome diz é um cache de saída. Isto significa que se receber a mesma requisição que já foi feita antes, em vez de processar tudo isto, ele pega o resultado final - que já está no cache - e envia para o requisitante.

Obviamente que se a requisição é diferente ou se o resultado já não está mais no cache por qualquer razão o aproveitamento não ocorrerá. O cache é um mecanismo do *controller*, não do *model*. Ele está vinculado às *actions*, não aos métodos auxiliares.

A pergunta não deixa claro mas me parece que primeiro a requisição é feita de um jeito e depois de outro jeito (precisa chamar outro método), então não há cache.

O tutorial mostrado indica claramente que o cache é outra coisa e deve ser usado de outra forma. Basta lê-lo.

Não é cache de banco de dados. Mesmo que fosse, em *queries* diferentes também não teria cache. De qualquer forma a pergunta não dá informações suficientes sequer pra saber se esta afirmação é verdadeira.

Cache não é algo mágico. Alias cache resolve problemas de sites de altíssimo tráfego, nos demais casos, embora nada crítico, o cache chega atrapalhar.

Comment: fiz uma edição na pergunta, mas se eu tenho uma classe que me retorna um numero, exemplo 50 (baseado nos segundos), se eu colocar essa classe com o outputcache ela não deveria retornar sempre 50 até o tempo do cache acabar?

Comment: @Dorathoto depende de como é usado. Como eu disse, a pergunta não deixa claro o exato contexto de como está sendo usado.

Comment: @Randrade é, vou acertar isso, ficou vago

Comment: @bigown como disse na pergunta "Porém quando estou usando em uma biblioteca que é chamada pela minha controller, parece que o cache não acontece." Tenho uma biblioteca e chamo ela na minha controller, em um html.helper, etc e parece q não faz o cache..

Comment: @Dorathoto editei para falar disto. Parece que você está achando que o cache é no *model* e não é.

Comment: então só posso utiliza-lo na Controller? então eu utilizo no html.Helper que crie e por isso não vai funcionar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37176/discussion-between-dorathoto-and-bigown).